# Make Math.max.apply read variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am fairly new to coding and tried something for fun, however I am struggling with it

```
function result() {
var n1 = document.getElementById("N1");
var n2 = document.getElementById("N2");
var n3 = document.getElementById("N3");
var a = [n1,n2,n3];
var temp = Math.max.apply(Math, a)
var out=document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = temp;
}
```

I am trying to make it output the numbers that are being input through HTML

```
<td><input class="textBox" id="N3" type="number"/></td>
```

However it wont read it as number and will just display NaN. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you need `temp` to be? The highest value entered?

Comment: `var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("N1").value)` etc

Comment: @BenM yes temp is supposed to be the highest number

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you! That is exactly what I need.

Comment: A faster way to this is `Math.max.apply(Math, ["N1", "N2", "N3"].map(function(id){return parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);}))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `temp` to be the highest value entered, the following will work:

```
function result() {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = Math.max(
        parseFloat( document.getElementById("N1").value ),
        parseFloat( document.getElementById("N2").value ),
        parseFloat( document.getElementById("N3").value )
    );
}
```

Some comments:

- Notice that we simply use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). `apply()` is not needed here, since you're explicitly calling the `max()` method.
- I'm assuming that `N1`, `N2`, etc. are `<input />` elements, so you need to get their value attribute using `.value`.
- We need to treat the values from the inputs as floats (or integers if that works), so we use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) (or [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) respectively). This isn't technically required in most modern browsers, but is good practice nevertheless.

Comment: Why do you think `1ruyrgjyes_!!%&"/)%&·)/&/)` should be treated as `1`? `parseFloat` and `parseInt` are bad ways of parsing arbitrary strings as numbers.

Comment: Yes, they are, but explaining the implications of casting using `Number()` (and dealing with `NaN` inside of `Math.max()`) is a whole other can of worms, which IMO is outside the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your n1, n2 and n3 are the elements not the values of the elements:

```
function result() {
var n1 = document.getElementById("N1").value;
var n2 = document.getElementById("N2").value;
var n3 = document.getElementById("N3").value;
var a = [n1,n2,n3];
var temp = Math.max.apply(Math, a)
    var out=document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = temp;
}
```